# Why can't ContT be made an instance of MonadError?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have a monad transformer stack including an `ErrorT` and I want to wrap a `ContT r` transformer around the whole thing. When I try to do that, my calls to `throwError` generate type errors - apparently `ContT r` isn't automatically an instance of `MonadError`. Fine, I thought - I'll just make it into one:

```
instance MonadError e m => MonadError e (ContT r m) where
  throwError = lift . throwError
  catchError = liftCatch . catchError
```

using some suitable definition of `liftCatch`. But now I get errors when compiling:

```
src\Language\Types.hs:68:10:
    Illegal instance declaration for `MonadError e (ContT r m)'
      (the Coverage Condition fails for one of the functional dependencies;
       Use -XUndecidableInstances to permit this)
    In the instance declaration for `MonadError e (ContT r m)'
```

I'm happy to use the UndecidableInstances pragma (I'm under the impression it's not too worrisome, e.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951382/making-a-custom-monad-transformer-an-instance-of-monaderror)) but I wondered if there was a difficulty in making the continuation transformer into an instance of `MonadError` - I guess that if it was fine, the authors of the `Control.Monad.Trans` package would have done it already... right?

Comment: It is fine, but does take UndecidableInstances which is too potentially dangerous and non-portable for the authors of the transformers library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ContT and ErrorT both allow non-standard control flow.  There is a way to wrap the ErrorT type around ContT in mtl:

```
instance (Error e, MonadCont m) => MonadCont (ErrorT e m)
```

But these two monad transformers do not commute. Remembering:

```
newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a}
newtype ErrorT e m a = ErrorT {runErrorT :: m (Either e a)}
newtype ContT r m a = ContT {runContT :: (a -> m r) -> m r}
```

`ErrorT String (ContT Bool Identity) ()` which is okay in package mtl could be:

```
ErrorT (ContT ( \ (k :: Either String () -> Identity Bool) -> k (Right ()) ) )
```

`ContT r (ErrorT e Identity) a` is not okay in package mtl.  But you can write it.

What are the semantics of (>>=) you want in the combined monad?  How do you expect your stack of nested error handlers to interact with nonlocal callCC?

Here is how I might write it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances   #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Cont
import Control.Monad.Error
import Data.Function
import Data.IORef

handleError :: MonadError e m => (e -> m a) -> m a -> m a
handleError = flip catchError

test2 :: ErrorT String (ContT () IO) ()
test2 = handleError (\e -> throwError (e ++ ":top")) $ do
  x <- liftIO $ newIORef 1
  label <- callCC (return . fix)
  v <- liftIO (readIORef x)
  liftIO (print v)
  handleError (\e -> throwError (e ++ ":middle")) $ do
    when (v==4) $ do
      throwError "ouch"
  when (v < 10) $ do
         liftIO (writeIORef x (succ v))
         handleError (\e -> throwError (e ++ ":" ++ show v)) label
  liftIO $ print "done"

go2 = runContT (runErrorT test2) (either error return)

{-

*Main> go2
1
2
3
4
*** Exception: ouch:middle:top

-}
```

So the above works with just the mtl, here is the new instance and how it works:

```
instance MonadError e m => MonadError e (ContT r m) where
  throwError = lift . throwError
  catchError op h = ContT $ \k -> catchError (runContT op k) (\e -> runContT (h e) k)

test3 :: ContT () (ErrorT String IO) ()
test3 = handleError (\e -> throwError (e ++ ":top")) $ do
  x <- liftIO $ newIORef 1
  label <- callCC (return . fix)
  v <- liftIO (readIORef x)
  liftIO (print v)
  handleError (\e -> throwError (e ++ ":middle")) $ do
    when (v==4) $ do
      throwError "ouch"
  when (v < 10) $ do
         liftIO (writeIORef x (succ v))
         handleError (\e -> throwError (e ++ ":" ++ show v)) label
  liftIO $ print "done"

go3 = runErrorT (runContT test3 return)

{-

*Main> go3
1
2
3
4
Left "ouch:middle:3:middle:2:middle:1:middle:top"

-}
```